# How to retrieve full data of record by its foreign key in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've been trying to figure out the proper way to get all the data from a record via a foreign key. I have  simple app where users can add books to their "bookshelf".

Here are my tables:

**USERS**

```
ID   |   NAME   |
```

**BOOKS**

```
ID   |   PAGES   |   NUMBER_OF_CHAPTERS
```

**BOOKSHELF**

```
ID   |   USER_ID (foreign key to `users.id`)   |
```

**BOOKSHELF_BOOKS**

```
ID   |   BOOKSHELF_ID (foreign key to `bookshelf.id`)   | BOOKS_ID (foreign key to `books.id`)
```

In my Eloquent Models, a `bookshelf` hasMany books and `bookshelf_books` belongsTo a `bookshelf`and I have set those up in my models.

What happens is users create a "bookshelf" and add books to it from the list of books.

I'm at the point where I need to render the bookshelf with the user's books.

When I retrieve my bookshelf books with a call like Bookshelf::find($id)->books, the books that belong to that bookshelf return just fine..but only columns from the bookshelf table. So I get in return the bookshelf id, the user id, and the book id.

What I want to have returned is all the data of the book itself when i query for books in the bookshelf, not just it's id. E.G. `[{"book_id":1, "pages":364, "number_of_chapters":14},{"book_id":2, "pages":211, "number_of_chapters":9}]`.

I've been scratching my head all day trying to figure out how to take this "join" one step further in Laravel/Eloquent ORM.

Would love any help with this, thanks!!

Comment: That should work: 
`DB::table('books')
        ->select('BOOKS.ID', 'BOOKS.PAGES','BOOKS.NUMBER_OF_CHAPTERS')
        ->join('BOOKSHELF_BOOKS', 'BOOKS.ID', '=', 'BOOKSHELF_BOOKS.BOOKS_ID')
        ->join('bookshelf', 'BOOKSHELF_BOOKS.BOOKSHELF_ID', '=', 'BOOKSHELF.ID')
        ->where('bookshelf.user_id', '=', $id_user)
        ->get();`

Comment: yes this worked, nice job Albert. I can't help but think there must be a cleaner way to do it with laravel's ORM though, perhaps wishful thinking

Comment: I can not try it but:
`$books = Book::join('BOOKSHELF_BOOKS', 'BOOKS.ID', '=', 'BOOKSHELF_BOOKS.BOOKS_ID')->join(....//rest of the joins `

Answer (score 21):

[Just eager load the relationship](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

Change

```
Bookshelf::find($id)->books
```

to

```
Bookshelf::with('books')->find($id)->books
```

Comment: Hi, is there anything I need to set up in my model relations for this? aside from the normal relationship?

Answer (score 3):

What about just doing it manually, and building your own array.

```
  $bookshelf = Bookshelf::find($id)->books;
  $thebooks = array();

  foreach($bookshelf as $val){
  $book = Book::find($val->book_id);
  $thebooks[] = $book;
  }
```

Then just return `$thebooks` to the View.  Which will be an array of book models.

Answer (score 2):

What you have should be correct.

`$bookshelf = Bookshelf::find($id)->books;`

To get your books, you would create a loop...

```
@foreach($bookshelf->books as $book)
   {{ $book->name }}
   {{ $book->title }}
@endforeach
```

To take this further, if you had an Author model which your books would `belongTo()`, you could even do something like..

```
@foreach($bookshelf->books as $book)
   {{ $book->name }}
   {{ $book->title }}
   {{ $book->author->name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this query

```
SELECT b.id, b.pages, b.number_of_chapters 
FROM bookshelf bs 
JOIN bookshelf_books bsb ON bsb.bookshelf_id = bs.id 
JOIN books b ON b.id = bsb.books_id 
WHERE bs.id = "Id of bookshelf"
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM BOOKSHELF_BOOKS 
JOIN BOOKSHELF ON BOOKSHELF_BOOKS.BOOKSHELF_ID = BOOKSHELF.ID 
JOIN USERS.ID = BOOKSHELF.USER_ID
```

Try this sql statement, it will work.