# Get ::all() Model data with Foreign key elements Laravel

Tags: laravel

In laravel with Model we can get all Table details

```
Locations::all();
```

But I want to get with Foreign key data with the all data.

like there is

**id , name , location_id**

so it has to get

location_id name

So i get it like

**id , name, location_id with location_id_Name**

Is it possible to get that result by using laravel basic model. Or I have to change some.

There is answer [How to retrieve full data of record by its foreign key in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873721/how-to-retrieve-full-data-of-record-by-its-foreign-key-in-laravel#17918477) But then I have to create a new function to add more component of each array. Which I don't want as I suspect there should be better way.

**Solution which i found**

```
Location::with('locationid')->get();
```

where loctionid declared in the model Location

```
public function locationid(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Location::class, 'location_id');
}
```

So now location load with parent. And also it is very much efficient. If anyone know what will better solution please just comment or answer it.
Best answer on stackoverflow look like https://stackoverflow.com/a/66187247/12657567

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the official documentation of Laravel framework. You may need `Eager Loading`.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Thanks for you i get what i want.

have some issue but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66185760/attempt-to-read-property-name-on-null solve problem which i have so everything fine